# multiprocessing.Pool().map multiple values for argument in worker function Error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hello fellow programmers!

I am trying to implement `multiprocessing` in a class, to reduce processing time of a program.

This is an abbreviation of the program:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

from functools import partial


class PlanningMachines():

    def __init__(self, machines, number_of_objectives, topology=False, episodes=None):
        ....


    def calculate_total_node_THD_func_real_data_with_topo(self):

        self.consider_topology = True

        func_part = partial(self.worker_function, consider_topology=self.consider_topology,
                            list_of_machines=self.list_of_machines, next_state=self.next_state, phase=phase, grid_topo=self.grid_topo,
                            total_THD_for_all_timesteps_with_topo=total_THD_for_all_timesteps_with_topo,
                            smallest_harmonic=smallest_harmonic, pol2cart=self.pol2cart, cart2pol=self.cart2pol,
                            total_THD_for_all_timesteps=total_THD_for_all_timesteps, harmonics_state_phase=harmonics_state_phase,
                            episode=self.episode, episodes=self.episodes, time_=self.time_, steplength=self.steplength,
                            longest_measurement=longest_measurement)

        with mp.Pool() as mpool:
            mpool.map(func_part, range(0, longest_measurement))


    def worker_function(measurement=None, consider_topology=None, list_of_machines=None, next_state=None, phase=None,
                        grid_topo=None, total_THD_for_all_timesteps_with_topo=None, smallest_harmonic=None, pol2cart=None,
                        cart2pol=None, total_THD_for_all_timesteps=None, harmonics_state_phase=None, episode=None,
                        episodes=None, time_=None, steplength=None, longest_measurement=None):

        .....
```

As you might know, one way of implementing parallel processing is using `multiprocessing.Pool().map`:

```
    with mp.Pool() as mpool:
        mpool.map(func_part, range(0, longest_measurement))
```

This function requires a `worker_function` which can be "packed" with `functools.partial`:

```
    func_part = partial(self.worker_function, consider_topology=self.consider_topology,
                        list_of_machines=self.list_of_machines, next_state=self.next_state, phase=phase, grid_topo=self.grid_topo,
                        total_THD_for_all_timesteps_with_topo=total_THD_for_all_timesteps_with_topo,
                        smallest_harmonic=smallest_harmonic, pol2cart=self.pol2cart, cart2pol=self.cart2pol,
                        total_THD_for_all_timesteps=total_THD_for_all_timesteps, harmonics_state_phase=harmonics_state_phase,
                        episode=self.episode, episodes=self.episodes, time_=self.time_, steplength=self.steplength,
                        longest_measurement=longest_measurement)
```

The Error is thrown when I try to execute `mpool.map(func_part, range(0, longest_measurement))`:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
TypeError: worker_function() got multiple values for argument 'consider_topology'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/train.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/train.py", line 77, in main
    duration = cf.training(episodes, env, agent, filename, topology=topology, multi_processing=multi_processing, CPUs_used=CPUs_used)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\RL_framework\help_functions\custom_functions.py", line 166, in training
    save_interval = parallel_training(range(episodes), env, agent, log_data_qvalues, log_data, filename, CPUs_used)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\RL_framework\help_functions\custom_functions.py", line 54, in paral

lel_training
    next_state, reward = env.step(action, state)                                                                # given the action, the environment gives back the next_state and the reward for the transaction for all objectives seperately
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\RL_framework\help_functions\environment_machines.py", line 127, in step
    self.calculate_total_node_THD_func_real_data_with_topo()                                                # THD_plant calculation with considering grid topo
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\RL_framework\help_functions\environment_machines.py", line 430, in calculate_total_node_THD_func_real_data_with_topo
    mpool.map(func_part, range(longest_measurement))
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: worker_function() got multiple values for argument 'consider_topology'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can `consider_topology` have multiple values if it is passed right before the `worker_function`:

```
self.consider_topology = True
```

I hope I could describe the my issue well enough for you to understand. Thank you in return.

Comment: shouldn't `worker_function()` be a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think is that your `worker_function` should be a static method.

What happens now is that you provide all values except the measurement variable in the partial call. You do this since this is the one value you are changing I'm guessing.

However since it is a class method it provides an instance of itself automatically as the first argument as well. You did not define self as the first argument of `worker_function` and now the class instance is inputted as your `measurement` input. The `range(0, longest_measurement)` you provide the map call is then inserted as the second input variable. Now since `consider_topology` is the second input parameter the function sees two values supplied for it, 1 the value in the `partial` call, and 2 the `map` call.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. This was exactly the problem. Now it works.